# cannot resolve symbol 'vrtoolkit'

Tags: android, google-cardboard

As a newbe to cardboard, I have created a simple pano app in Android Studio by trying to duplicate the google cardboard sample simplepanowidget. The java activity class shows the vrtoolkit as being unresolved, e.g. in import statements such as:
    import com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.widgets.pano.VrPanoramaEventListener;

I am trying to include the appropriate library but do not know which one it should be: is it libvrtoolkit.so or in a .aar archive?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty obvious (after unzipping and looking in the class tree for panowidget provided with the google cardboard sample): it is in panowidget.aar.